# Python tkinter frame not showing properly

Tags: python, tkinter

The banner_strip frame does not show up when i uncomment the line starting with `main_frame= self.create_widget`....

if the line is commented out then it shows up as i want it. Also when i pass `row = 0` instead of 1 to `self.banner_strip = self.create_widget()` and then uncomment the above mentioned line then this strip frame shows up but in the middle of the frame above the label 'This is some text'. Any idea what am i doing wrong here?

```
from tkinter import *

class Application():
    def __init__(self, master):

        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("700x400+250+150")
        self.master.resizable(False, False)

        self.banner_frame = self.create_widget(master_widget = self.master, widget = Frame(), width = 700, height = 70, bg = '#255869', row = 0, column = 0, bd = 0)
        self.banner_label = self.create_widget(master_widget = self.banner_frame, widget = Label(), bg = '#255869', row = 0, column = 0, pady = 20, text = "This is some text")
        self.banner_strip = self.create_widget(master_widget = self.banner_frame, widget = Frame(), width = 700, height = 10, bg = '#BCC947', row = 1, column = 0)
        #self.main_frame = self.create_widget(self.master, widget = Frame(), width = 700, height = (400 - 80), bd = 0, row = 1, column = 0)

    def create_widget(self, master_widget = None, widget = None, width = 0, height = 0, bg  = None, fg = None, row = 0, column = 0, text = None, bd = None, padx = 0, pady = 0 ):
        widget_type = type(widget)(width = width, height = height, bg = bg, fg  = fg, text = text, bd = bd)
        widget_type.grid(row = row, column = column)
        return widget_type

cl = Tk()
c = Application(cl)
cl.mainloop()
```

Please help me if someone knows the solution. Thank you!

Edit: This is the exact same program but without using the method `create_widget()`. In this one `label_frame row=0` and `main_frame row=1` works perfectly fine

```
from tkinter import *

class Application():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("700x400+250+150")
        self.master.title("GetCaseQob v2.1")

        self.master.resizable(False, False)

        self.banner_frame = Frame(master, width = 700, height = 70, bd = 0, bg = '#255869')
        self.banner_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

        self.banner_strip = Frame(self.banner_frame, width = 700, height = 10, bd = 0, bg = '#BCC947')
        self.banner_strip.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

        self.banner = Label(self.banner_frame, bg = '#255869', text = 'This is some text')
        self.banner.grid(row = 0, column = 0, pady = 20)

        self.main_frame = Frame(master, width = 700, height = (400-70), bd = 0)
        self.main_frame.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        self.main_frame.grid_propagate(0)

cl = Tk()
c = Application(cl)
cl.mainloop()
```

Comment: is this just a duplicate of  your original question with a better example? If so, instead of creating another question you should edit the original. We don't need two questions asking the same thing.

Comment: I deleted the previous question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

It appears the real problem is you are missing one of your variables in your `widget_type = type(widget)` line. You do not have `master_widget` being used to define each widget.

Change:

```
widget_type = type(widget)(width = width, height = height, bg = bg, fg  = fg, text = text, bd = bd)
```

To:

```
widget_type = type(widget)(master_widget, width = width, height = height, bg = bg, fg  = fg, text = text, bd = bd)
```

This will correct your framing issue but you will see some changes on the spacing of the layouts. This will have to be dealt with as well.

Because I am not sure why you are setting up your widgets the way you are doing them I have created a modified version of you code with a more traditional way of writhing the GUI.

```
from tkinter import *

class Application():
    def __init__(self, master):

        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("700x400+250+150")
        self.master.resizable(False, False)

        self.banner_frame = Frame(self.master, width = 700, height = 70, bg = '#255869', bd = 0)
        self.banner_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.banner_label = Label(self.banner_frame, bg = '#255869', text = "This is some text")
        self.banner_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, pady = 20)
        self.banner_strip = Frame(self.banner_frame, width = 700, height = 10, bg = '#BCC947')
        self.banner_strip.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        self.main_frame = Frame(self.master, width = 700, height = (400 - 80), bd = 0)
        self.main_frame.grid(row = 1, column = 0)


cl = Tk()
c = Application(cl)
cl.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you it definitely worked. However could you please explain why i have to set row = 2 when self.banner_frame and self.main_frame are child of self.master (root frame...so banner_frame should be 0 and main_frame should be 1??) and self.label and self.banner_strip are child of self.banner_frame (that way self.label row= 0 and self.banner_strip row = 1).

Comment: @FaisalKhan I have updated my answer as I have found the main issue causing the problem.

Comment: @FaisalKhan I have also added a modified version of the code that is more in line with how one would normally write their GUI as the way you are doing it does seam to be a bit unorthodox.

Comment: Ah it seems like we posted at the same time :D. I did the way u have done it in your answer but i am designing a GUI where i have around 30 to 40 different widgets and for every widget, repeating the same code (i.e grid etc) makes it difficult to debug. That is why i wanted to do it by using a method and pass desired parameters

Comment: @FaisalKhan If you have to repeat yourself when making widgets you might consider using a list or dictionary as the preferred method. This makes troubleshooting and maintainability much better in the long run.